# Get rspec controller test to do a shallow comparison of BigDecimals

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controller, bigdecimal

I have an rspec controller with the test:

```
it "assigns all rate_card_details as @rate_card_details" do
  rate_card_detail = FactoryGirl.create(:rate_card_detail)
  get :index, {}, valid_session
  assigns(:rate_card_details).should eq([rate_card_detail])
end
```

For most models, this works fine. However, in this case, the `rate` field is a decimal. This causes the rspec comparison to (for some reason) compare 1 instance of BigDecimal with another, including its location in memory. Here is the error:

```
 Failure/Error: assigns(:rate_card_details).should eq([rate_card_detail])

   expected: [#<RateCardDetail rate_card_id: 1, item_id: 1, rate: #<BigDecimal:7f82dcdb0ae0,'0.6941E2',18(18)>, created_at: "2013-06-05 18:12:53", updated_at: "2013-06-05 18:12:53">]
        got: [#<RateCardDetail rate_card_id: 1, item_id: 1, rate: #<BigDecimal:7f82dc9a74d0,'0.6941E2',18(18)>, created_at: "2013-06-05 18:12:53", updated_at: "2013-06-05 18:12:53">]
```

The 2 BigDecimals have the same value, but are different objects. Is there a way to get rspec to treat these as equal when doing a comparison?

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't the different array instances? E.g., did you try `...should =~ [rate_card_detail]` or `...should match_array([rate_card_details])`? I can't test anything ATM.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the suggestion. I tried both of those, and neither work. They both cause "collection contained" errors where the actual does not match the expected - similar with missing elements and extra elements.

Comment: does `assigns(:rate_card_details).to_yaml.should eq([rate_card_detail]).to_yaml` work?

Comment: I meant `assigns(:rate_card_details).to_yaml.should eq([rate_card_detail].to_yaml)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not pretty but this works with me

```
it "assigns all rate_card_details as @rate_card_details" do
  rate_card_detail = FactoryGirl.create(:rate_card_detail)
  get :index, {}, valid_session
  assigns(:rate_card_details).first.attributes.values.each_with_index do |rcd,i|
    r_c_d = rate_card_detail[i]
    if rcd.is_a?BigDecimal
      rcd = rcd.to_s
      r_c_d = r_c_d.to_s
    end
    expect(rcd).to eq(r_c_d)
  end
end
```